# Tailwind CSS Breakpoints

Tags: html, css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-css

I can't figure out why the responsive breakpoints of tailwind css are not working in my project.

Suppose, I'd like to add some padding in my parent div and want to minimise it on the md & lg screen size but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="text-grey-4 flex-1 lg:px-6 md:px-4 px-0 sm:text-left text-center self-center"><h2 class="h2"><b>Heading Text</b></h2><div> Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum lorum ispum lorum ipsum</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Tailwind-css` follows `mobile-first` breakpoint system.

Any default style added will be considered for `mobile` devices and classes for `medium` and `large` devices needs to be specified seperately.

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="py-2 md:py-32 lg:py-64 text-4xl">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

##### Output in mobile device:

[image]

##### Output in medium device:

[image]

##### Output in large device:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter to add the Mobile Screen size first and then add the MD & LG size but according to your explanation and your code. I have tried your scenario but no response is coming from this.

Comment: Please try this and change the orientation of the output screen and let me know if it works https://play.tailwindcss.com/qwuGth4fdF

Comment: It works on a tailwind playground but doesn't work in my project..

Comment: you must be having configuration problem

Comment: I have summarize all the problem look at my config file....

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["public/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: check with class name `text-red-800`  and tell me if you see red text ?